# An inequality for condition $x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=1$

Tags: inequality

Let $x_{i}>0,i=1,2,\cdots,n$, and such $x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}=1$, show that
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1-x_{i}}\right)\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_{i}\right)\le n$$

since
$$1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}(1-x_{i})$$
it suffices to show that
$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1-x_{i}}\right)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}(1-x_{i})\right)\le n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\dfrac 1 {1-x_i} \ge \dfrac 1 {1-x_j} \Leftrightarrow x_i (1-x_i)\ge x_j (1-x_j)$  using Chebyshev inequality

$(\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac 1 {1-x_i})(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i (1-x_i))\le  n\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac 1 {1-x_i} \cdot x_i(1-x_{i} )=n $

Comment: @Booldy Could you please explain exactly how you use Chebyshev’s inequality to reach your conclusion?

Comment: statement is if a_1>=a_2>=...a_n, and b_1>=b_2>=...b_n  then

Comment: (a_1+a_2+...-a_n)(b_1+b_2+...+b_n)<=n(a_1b_1+...-a_nb_n)

Comment: you can easily conclude it by rearanging the terms,using gready alghoritm